# Where do I inject the $timeout function in my controller

Tags: angularjs

Where do I inject the $timeout function in my controller? I'm still getting `$timeout function not defined` message. I'm guessing I need it somewhere above the function method as well.

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular
        .module("taskManagement")
        .controller("TaskListCtrl",
        ["taskResource",
            TaskListCtrl]);

    function TaskListCtrl(taskResource, $timeout) {
        var vm = this;

        taskResource.query(function (data) {
            vm.tasks = data;
        });

        vm.updateStatus = function (task) {
            debugger;
            task.status = task.status == 1 ? 0 : 1;

            taskResource.save({ id: task.id, status: task.status },
                function () {
                    vm.msg = 'Saved.';
                    $timeout(function () { vm.msg = '' }, 3000);
                });
        }
    }
}());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost have it, you also need to add it to the `.controller` list in the same order as your TaskListCtrl function.

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular
        .module("taskManagement")
        .controller("TaskListCtrl",
        ["taskResource", "$timeout",
            TaskListCtrl]);

    function TaskListCtrl(taskResource, $timeout) {
```